# create a JSON object from a string array in java

Tags: java, json

I have an array of strings like `[1234_acb,2345_xyz]`
I want to form a key value pair JSON Object like `[{"1234":"abc"},{"2345":"xyz"}]`
I have used split function to separate out the values from underscore

Comment: Which language you are using ? And show what you tried ?

Comment: @CoderofCode  I am using Java, for (String str : stringArray){
            for (String s : str.split("_")){
             stringList.add(s);
            }
         }

Comment: Here is the answer which will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306271/create-key-value-pairs-string-in-json

Answer (score 0):

assume your string data is stored in `data`:

```
String keyValArray[] = data.split("_");
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

for(int a=0;a<keyValArray.length-1;a+=2){
    jsonArray.put(new JSONObject().put(keyValArray[a], keyValArray[a+1]));
}//for loop
String jsonStr = jsonArray.toString();
```

**P.S:** `for` loop limit is `keyValArray.length-1` so `keyValArray[a+1]` does not go out of the array bound

**P.S2:** @njzk2 `a++` changed to `a+=2`, to skip the value item in array, so it's not used as a key in the json object

Comment: I would say it does not work as intended if what is intended was clearer

Comment: not entirely sure, but It is clear that if `keyValArray` contains more than 2 elements, your solution will look weird.

Comment: @njzk2 guess so, i think it should be `a+=2` instead of `a++`

Comment: that would work if the input was like `key1_value1_key2_value2...`

Comment: @njzk2 i think thats what the op want. Hopefuly :)