# Returning string representation of key value pairs in JSONArray

Tags: java, json

```
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
                System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).names());
            }
```

Will print pairs, and then individual objects, such as

```
{"key1":"a"}
["key1"]
{"key2":"b"}
["key2"]
{"key3":"c"}
["key3"]
{"key4":"d"}
["key4"]
...
{"keyn":"end"}
["keyn"]
```

I'm wanting the for loop to be able to grab the string interpretation of the key and value for each object separately.

I've been searching through the [JSONObject API](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) but I can't seem to find a method in there that would do that. It's easy to grab the name of a value if you know the name of the key:

```
jsonObject.getString(whenYouKnowTheKeyName));
```

But when I'm looping through an array I'm assuming I know neither. I'm looking to get

```
key1
a
key2
b
key3
c
key4
d
...
```

as the output. I'm attempting to read from an already created JSON object, not create a new one.

Comment: did you try `keys and names` methods of JSONObject?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create key-value pairs string in JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306271/create-key-value-pairs-string-in-json)

Comment: @michaelsnowden If I am not mistaken, I believe this question is actually the exact opposite of that one, and not a dupe.

Comment: @gla3dr Those answers include a way to get the string representation of the object. It's just toString, but that seems easier than anything else.

Comment: @Baddie I did try `keys and names`, names was closer to what I want but isn't exactly what I'm looking for because it returns a JSONObject and not a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the objects in `jsonArray` always contain exactly one key, the following should print the key and value in each object as you would like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
    String key = keys.next();
    Object value = jsonObject.get(key);
    System.out.println(key);
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

However, you may want to handle all the keys of all the objects by wrapping each key and value in a `while (keys.hasNext())` iterator loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = keys.next();
        Object value = jsonObject.get(key);
        System.out.println(key);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

With your example, both solutions have the same output, but obviously the latter is more flexible.